# Does gap closing and reopening guarantee a non-trivial topological phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topology, topological-insulators

I know that a Dirac point carries a Chern number of $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and when we have a gap closure at any point in our band structure we can transfer Chern numbers depending on at how many points we have gap closure. My question is, that if we start with a topologically trivial phase and close the gap and reopen it, are we guaranteed to have a topologically non-trivial phase?

For example, in [HgTE quantum wells](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1148047) we get a non-trivial phase after band inversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take a free scalar theory
$$
L=(d\phi)^2-m^2\phi^2
$$

If you scan $m\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, you go through the point $m=0$, where the gap closes. On either side, the theory is in the trivial topological phase.

You could do the same using free fermions,
$$
L=\bar\psi d\psi-m\bar\psi\psi
$$
As you scan $m\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, you again go through a gapless point. On either side, the theory may or may not be trivial. For example, in two dimensions, you get a non-trivial phase if and only if the number of fermion modes is odd. If you take an even number, then you are in the trivial phase on either side of $m=0$. In 3d you get a non-trivial phase for any number of fermions. In 4/5/6d you get a trivial phase regardless of the number of fermions. $d=7$ is similar to $d=3$. Etc.

Comment: Maybe a useful side-comment: the answer is 'yes' if the gap-closing is specified to be ungappable/unavoidable. (This is a consequence from noting that: (1) free-fermion systems do not have locally-stable accidental transitions, and (2) all non-trivial phases of free-fermion systems are topological (e.g. no option for symmetry-breaking).)

Comment: How are you defining non-topological here? My thinking is related to non-zero berry curvature integrating over the Brillouin zone.

Comment: @RaghavChaturvedi In full generality, non-topological means trivially gapped, i.e., there is a mass gap below which there is a single state, and the path integral evaluates to $1$ on every manifold.